# Как сравнить два списка?

Tags: python

Извините за глупый вопрос.

```
g = ['mon1-1','mon2-2','mon3-3']
g2 = ['mon1-1','mon2-2']
```

Как сравнить g с g2 (два списка), если значение не найдет, вывести только то, что не нашел, а это будет переменная mon3-3.

Answer (score 8):

Если по скорости некритично, то можно так:

```
for e in g:
    if not e in g2:
        print e
```

Вот так можно получить список всех нужных элементов:

```
g = [e for e in g if not e in g2]
```

Побыстрее будет, если использовать множества:

```
ss = set(g) - set(g2)
```

но этот способ работает, только если неважна кратность элементов.

Comment: Для этого есть кнопка "Принять ответ"